# Alpha wave changes and brain waves shutdown vs sexual actions

Tags: brain, sexuality, brain-waves

I liked to know more about brain waves and sexual actions ( like foreplay, orgasm, etc).

So I found this [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0MZ__8jWKMFvuepr1VMWjZcnu6QoGGA/view?usp=drivesdk) :

([REVIEW:New Electroencephalogram (EEG) Neuroimaging Methods of Analyzing Brain Activity Applicable to the Study of Human Sexual Response](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1743609515325613)):

[image]

So I seen [this e-book](https://books.google.com/books?id=vcTJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA100&dq=orgasm%20brain%20wave%20beta%20alpha&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6pJ3m29zmAhUCLFAKHf8fBS8Q6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=orgasm%20brain%20wave%20beta%20alpha&f=false) :

[image]

These parts:

[image]

So as you can see above, the author said the brain wave shut down and there is some **height change in alpha wave**.

- So i like to know more about the **brain wave shutdown condition**
  could be happened about similar situation with this condition ( brain wave shutdown )?
- And why the alpha wave has huge change and **not discussed** other brain waves ?
- Also for better understanding some similar known situation and effect of these two conditions?

Thanks.

Comment: Without digging any further, on face that book looks to me to not be very reputable. The descriptions are very amateurish and sound like the words of someone who is not any sort of authority in EEG. "seized up"/"shutdown" of alpha is just...nonsense.

Comment: Regarding what is written in the book, it doesn't seem professional at all. "... nearly all brainwave activity seemed to shut down" means nothing. This is not the way how EEG is reported. Intuitively, a decrease in alpha power and an increase of the power in lower band might be true. but this report gave me nothing, specifically that the reference was a website. I remember an fMRI study I read before which has a scientific experimental structure. I try to find it and share it here for you.

Comment: Thanks @Majid jan, maybe we have the same nationality.